# Branching structure while migrating from SVN to GIT

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch

Currently at my organization, we use SVN to manage all our code. The current hierarchy that we follow in SVN is

- parent1

  - branches

    - developer

      - project1
      - project2
    - release

      - project1
      - project2
  - tags
  - trunk
- parent2

  - branches

    - developer

      - project3
      - project4
    - release

      - project3
      - project4
  - tags
  - trunk

Now while migrating to git, i would like to know what would be the best possible way to replace this in git? The 'parent' level is just to group the projects. It can be omitted. The projects might also have inter dependency. Any kind of suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Branching strategy is not really dependent on Git or SVN per se.  You could use the same strategy in Git if you want to.  Note that in Git creating a branch is potentially much cheaper than a tool like SVN (or Perforce).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen how do i group the projects in git and also later on i should be able to clone all the projects in a parent

Answer (score 0):

I would make a distinct git repository for each of your projects, so you can have separate lifecycles.

First, you need to flatten your `branches/` directories. Rename them in `svn` beforehand (`svn mv ^/parent1/branches/developer/project1 ^/parent1/branches/developer_project1` etc., then `svn rm ^/parent1/branches/developer`).

After that, you end up with the standard svn structure (`/trunk`, `/branches`, `/tags`) and can simply migrate. `git svn clone` will recognize said directory names (or rather, you'll specify them with `-T`, `-t` and `-b`, including your `/parent1`'s) and do the correct thing.

Comment: A branch name like `developer/project1` is fine in Git; there's no need to flatten anything.

Comment: @chepner, does `git svn clone` really figure out that there are not *two* branches `developer` and `release` but *n* branches `{developer,release}/xyz` ? That's more magic than I'd expect, even knowing `git`'s usual greatness. ;) I would expect it to make those two branches, with  `project1/, project2/ ...` as top-level directories, which of course would be wildly wrong. Can you elaborate?

Comment: The end result is allowable; I'm not sure how you would actually implement it with `git svn` (or some other migration tool). You could explicitly name the various branch directories in the `clone` command (`git svn clone --branches branches/developer --branches branches/release`); I'm not sure what the resulting branch names in Git would be, but it might be a step in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, `/` might be allowable in git branch names, the problem is `git svn clone` step in which `git` must recognize and distinguish which branches exist *in svn*. At this point, I'm pretty sure there is no syntax to tell it to make a git branch named `release/project1` (and so on) from the original directory. Flattening the branch namespace in the svn tree costs nothing, is done quickly, works guaranteed and I'd therefore stick with that answer.